# Send values from one browser tab to another in nextjs and populate formik form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, next.js, formik

I have a form in next with a single input e.g. name on my page. On submit I would like the browser to open a new tab which contains a form with more inputs e.g. name, address, age. How can I pre-populate the name in the new tab?

I was considering the useContext hook but as far as I can tell that does not work across tabs. Do I need to use Redux at this point?

Edit: My attempt using localStorage so far:

```
// User inputs name which on submit is
// saved to local storage and /register page is opened
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
          initialValues={{ name: '' }}
          onSubmit={(values) =>
            localStorage.setItem('name', values.name)
          }
        >
          {() => (
            <Form>
              <div>
                <InputBox
                  type="text"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  htmlFor="name"
                  label="Name"
                  placeholder=""
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  // ? Not sure using window is the correct way to do this in nextjs
                  onClick={(event) => window.open('/register', '_blank')}       
                >
                  Start KYC
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          )}
    </Formik>
)
```

```
import { Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik'
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from 'react'

const Register: NextPage = () => {
  let nameInit = ''
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('You are on the browser')
      // ️ can use localStorage here
    } else {
      console.log('You are on the server')
      // ️ can't use localStorage
    }
    nameInit = localStorage.getItem('name') ?? ''
    console.log(nameInit)
  }, [])
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: nameInit,
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        console.log(values)
      }}
    >
      {() => (
        <Form className="space-y-8 divide-y divide-gray-200">
          <div className="sm:col-span-2">
            <label
              htmlFor="name"
            >
              First name
            </label>
            <Field
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="name"
              autoComplete="given-name"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end">
            <button
              type="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

Inspecting the page I can see that the value is being set and the console.log at the end of the `useEffect` also returns the expected value. But the form is still not being populated... My guess is the form is rendered before the useEffect is executed? When I just write the code in the function body instead of using useEffect it seems that is being executed on the server where localStorage is not available.

Comment: A new tab/window will be a *new* instance of your app running. Using localStorage will probably be the easiest way to allow multiple browser windows to access the same "state"/data. Web sockets could be an alternative. Redux alone won't help because it only lives in memory and would need to be persisted to longer-term storage, a.k.a. localStorage, to be useful/accessible from another window/tab. What have you tried already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you use getServerSideProps?

Comment: @Matt I plan to do so in future as an optimization but I need to learn more about it

Comment: How many input fields do you need to pre-populate? I can post a nice answer with get serversideprops if that would help

Comment: That would be amazing. The first form has one field which needs to be pre-populated in the second form which has 5.

Answer (score 0):

You're closer than you think! It works across tabs, but you might be using `<link>` or `<a>` tags to navigate.

If you use the built in next/link, your app won't refresh and useContext will work for you. Your app will also take advantage of Next JS's speed optimisations. Example:

```js
import Link from "next/link"

const Nav = () => (
  <Link href="gosomewhere">
    <a>I'm a Link</a>
  </Link>
)
```

Comment: As far as I know this would not work since I can't use `Link` as form submission right? - It has to be a button.